# NumLock Turns Letters Into Numbers on Desktop Computer

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, numlock

I just got a new desktop PC with Windows 10 Pro x64, and for some reason NumLock "turns" letters like k, l, etc. into numbers, even though I have a proper keyboard with a proper number pad.

Every related article/forum post on the Internet I was able to find dealt with laptops that don't have a number pad, where this is normal and has been the case for years. This is the first time however that I see the issue on desktop computers. Is it possible to make Windows 10 behave like previous versions in this situation?

Note: Unplugging and replugging the keyboard solves the problem, but after a system reboot, it becomes "bad" again, so I need to do this after each restart and would like to know the cause / a solution.

Edit: The keyboard is a standard TEAC TK-8060 keyboard.

Comment: What is the make and model of your desktop?

Comment: I'm not sure what details you're looking for, but I assume that what's relevant is the motherboard and keyboard: they are, ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming motherboard, and a standard TEAC USB keyboard. I am assuming that it's a Windows 10 problem because the same keyboard connected to another PC doesn't have this problem, and it's hard to believe that any other hardware could be causing this. But maybe you know something I don't :)

Comment: What happens if you reboot? Unplug the keyboard and plug it in again?

Comment: Try running the on screen keyboard (`osk`). Does the problem happen with the OSK as well? Then goto OSK > Options > Turn on Numeric Keypad > Press Numlock on OSK. Close OSK. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the existence of OSK. For the record it didn't happen in OSK. In any case, the way I connected the PC it was really difficult to unplug/replug the keyboard, so I hadn't tried this basic step, it did solve the problem (rebooting didn't help). Do you know the cause though? Is there a way to solve it through Windows without unplugging the keyboard?

Comment: I don't know the cause, sorry :/ If it happens a lot you could buy a short USB extension cable which will make it easier for you to unplug/plug your keyboard.

Comment: Just adding a note: restarting the computer actually resets the keyboard to the bad state, i.e. if NumLock is on, many letters turn into numbers until I unplug and replug the keyboard.

Comment: There may be an option in your BIOS that sets the NumLk State on startup. If there is try setting it to off.

Comment: Looked through all the options, couldn't find it. If anyone knows though, please share. It's the standard ASUS UEFI interface.

Comment: 'Bootup Numlock State' switch in the Boot section of the BIOS? http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/3224/uefisettings.png

Comment: Thanks. It actually looks a bit different, but I found it, unfortunately it doesn't help, clicking Num Lock still gives numbers in place of the right-hand letters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved in one of the Windows updates in May.

Unfortunately I cannot point to the exact update, but this it is certainly from the last week of April or the first two weeks of May 2016.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, it seems that it happens only with several keyboards.
Finally I solved it this way (sorry, but I've got Polish language set):

- Step 1 - Go to keyboard driver properties using Device Manager and select Update driver
- [Step 2 - Select Browse my computer, then Allow me to choose from drivers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Kjl.png)
- [Step 3 - Uncheck "Show compatible hardware"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVzsO.png)

Now find something like "Standard keyboard device" on the drivers list, install it (click Yes in the compatibility warning window) and check if keyboard is still working.

If so - reboot Your computer and enjoy fixed keyboard without letters turning into numbers.
If not - revert driver back and try another one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense, but I couldn't find any standard keyboard device in the list except the standard PS/2 keyboard which doesn't work. The "HID Keyboard Device" is the one I'm already using. The keyboard is a TEAC TK-8060 (fairly standard wired USB keyboard).

Comment: Problem returned after several days, sorry for bad answer. Does anybody know anything about this problem?